# MonacaでボタンなどのコントロールのCSS変更

Tags: monaca, css, jquery-mobile

現在MonacaのボタンなどのコントロールのCSSを変更したいとおもっているのですが、反映されません。
jquery mobileをプロジェクトに追加前はCSSを変更できたのですが。

コードは以下のようになっています。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <style type="text/css">

    input#button { 
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        }

    </style>    
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <div  data-role="page" id="TopPage">
    <section data-role="content">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
    <a href="#changepage" data-icon="plus" class="ui-btn-right">Add</a>
    </header>
        <br />
        This is a template for Monaca app.
        <br />
        ボタン<input type='button' name='button' value='サンプル' onclick='change()' id="button"><br />
        テキスト<input type='text' name='text' size="40"><br />
        パスワード<input type='password' name='password'><br />
        ラジオボタン<input type='radio' name='radio'>　<input type='radio' name='radio'><br />
        チェックボックス<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox'><br />
        コンボボックス
        <select name="select" class="bsize" id="selBox0" onChange="getSelect(0,this.value)">
        <option value="test1">test1</option>
        <option value="test2">test2</option>
        <option value="test3">test3</option>
        </select>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function change(){
                $.mobile.changePage("#changepage");
        }
        </script>
    </section>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="changepage">
        <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
        </header>
        <section data-role="content">
        <table>
            <tr>
             <td>名前：</td>
             <td><input type=text name="namae"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>パスワード：</td>
             <td><input type=password name="passwd"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>性別：</td>
             <td>
              <input type=radio name="seibetsu" value="male" checked>男
              <input type=radio name="seibetsu" value="female">女
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>趣味：</td>
             <td>
              <input type=checkbox name="shumi" value="PC">パソコン
              <input type=checkbox name="shumi" value="SP">スポーツ
              <input type=checkbox name="shumi" value="RD">読書
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td>
              <input type=submit value=" 送信 ">
              <input type=reset value=" 取消 ">
             </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </section>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

ご協力お願いします。